# Spread operator issue: {...someObject, someField: "someValue"} being treated as a function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, setstate, spread

I'm getting the following error when trying to set state using the below code:

> "Argument type function(any): any & {field1: string} is not assignable
> to parameter type ((prevState: {field1: string, field3: string,
> field2: string}) => {field1: string, field3: string, field2: string})
> | {field1: string, field3: string, field2: string}   Type string is
> not assignable to type undefined     Type function(any): any &
> {field1: string} is not assignable to type (prevState: {field1:
> string, field3: string, field2: string}) => {field1: string, field3:
> string, field2: string}"

```
const ExampleApp = (props) => {
    const [someState, setSomeState] = useState({
        field1: "initialValue1",
        field2: "initialValue2",
        field3: "initialValue3",
    });

    const updateField1 = (newValue1) => {
        setSomeState(prevState => {
            return {...prevState, field1: newValue1};
        });
    }   
}
```

I can fix this by calling my object as though it were a function

```
    const updateField1 = (newValue1) => {
      setSomeState(prevState => {
            return {...prevState, field1: newValue1}();
        });
    }
```

I can also just use:

```
const updateField1 = (newValue1) => {
    setSomeState({...someState, field1: newValue1});
}
```

But my understanding is that to get the most recent value of someState under certain circumstances, I must use an arrow function which has access to prevState.

My question is, why would this be treated as a function and why does the following not need to be treated as a function?

```
  const updateField1 = (newValue1) => {
      setSomeState(prevState => {
          return {...prevState};
      });
  }
```

I'll note this is virtually identical to an example given on the W3schools website which also contains this same error

```
 function Car() {
    const [car, setCar] = useState({
      brand: "Ford",
      model: "Mustang",
      year: "1964",
      color: "red"
    });

    const updateColor = () => {
      setCar(previousState => {
        return { ...previousState, color: "blue" }
      });
    }
  }
```

https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usestate.asp

Comment: Is that your exact code? I'm not receiving that TypeScript error when I paste it in.

Comment: Indeed - can you take [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN1wC+cAZlBCHAORTo4DGMVA3ALABQH9EAdqvAFEAHjnAAbdAEEwYOAF44ACjDkwqAFxwcPAJ4BKeQD5EHOGbjc+8ANqoKWXPgA0cDDEz3sedAF15KDC98RQRTc3CSYHQxABMARk0AImAeYBhgHDEANUzkdDjEpzDws0jomIAmJJS0jOzc9ArC4pKy2IBmatT0zJyxPPbm9nDCPTZOYfNLfhQwGO8AMSjYuP9FHnQAdz68hK1dAzljUMmS13R3T0d0ZVoANyCCI5NTs-NaGGQoHkQAOn+VOgHtcXG14klEoRxm8iGMWsQzBxCEA) as a starting point and try to reproduce the error?  I am not able to see the error you are seeing, suggesting this code is not like the code you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have provided should work fine. I have extended it slightly to render out the state and it runs without issue:

```
const ExampleApp = (props) => {
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState({
      field1: "initialValue1",
      field2: "initialValue2",
      field3: "initialValue3",
  });

  const updateField1 = (newValue1) => {
      setSomeState(prevState => {
          return {...prevState, field1: newValue1};
      });
  }   

  return (
    <div>
      <p>state: {JSON.stringify(someState)}</p>
      <button onClick={() => updateField1("foo")}>Update state</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Looks like it was just an issue with some linting I added, cheers